# HTTPWebRequest fails when setting CookieContainer

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I used the Fiddler extension RequestToCode to replay a POST from logging into Yahoo.

When I run the code, I can see in Fiddler that the login was successful and there are 10 cookies in the response.

In my code though, the response.Cookies had a count of 0.

So I updated my HTTPWebRequest and set:

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

When I run the code again and look at it in Fiddler I see the login failed because the response navigates to a failed login url.

My ultimate goal is to get the cookies from the login attempt to use in a later Get request to Yahoo.

Why is setting the cookie container causing a failure?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you initializing new `CookieContainer` on every request. 
Declare public variable `CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();`

Now your new requests will use the same `CookieContainer`, example:

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en,hr;q=0.9");
    request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "");
    request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well. In my code I am only making one HttpWebRequest, which is to login to yahoo.com. When I make the request without setting request.CookieContainer to anything I see in Fiddler that the request was successful. Request.cookies is empty though. When I set request.CookieContainer to  new CookieContainer() and make the request to login then the request fails (as seen in Fiddler).

Comment: @cmptrer You can't send login requests directly. You first need to send GET request on login.yahoo.com so you can get crumb and acrumb tokens. You will also need to set browser-fp-data in your request otherwise it won't work. While you doing this request you will also store Cookies in CookieContainer. You can't do POST request for login with empty CookieContainer.